# Check if base class has specific constructor

Tags: c++, static-assert

Let's say we a base class with a specific constructor and a pure virtual member function. 
Is there a way to check if the base class has this constructor?

```
struct Base {
    explicit Base(int);
    virtual void foo() = 0;

};

static_assert(std::is_constructible<Base, int>::value); //this fails since Base is abstract
```

**[EDIT]**

There is this case:

```
template<typename T>
class Derived : T {
    Derived() : T{42} {
    };
};
```

I want to make sure, that the base class has this specific constructor and provide a good error message via static_assert

Comment: Perhaps testing with an empty derived class, but what are you trying to achieve? You should know its public interface in any case.

Comment: Did you try the approach of using `decltype` to see if the constructor can be manually invoked from a `declval`ed pointer to the object?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @ShadowMitia How can empty derived class help to check existence of specific base class constructor?

Comment: I've edited the question to provide information about my case

Comment: @SamVarshavchik no I didn't tried it. Do you have an example?

Comment: I believe the question you are asking as-is, is impossible to achieve with any existing type traits/concepts. You will probably need to provide more information about your concrete use case for us to help. Alternatively, you may need to enlist the help of a source generator tool that can give you reflection capabilities if the problem is that important.

Comment: But the requirement you've added is a requirement on the type `T`, not on the type `Base`. `Base` is perfectly happy with or without a constructor that takes `int`. It's only when you use it as that template argument that you need that constructor, and when you do that, if the constructor isn't there, you'll get an error message.

Comment: @pptaszni That just plain [doesn't work](https://godbolt.org/z/a9fsezzG6). `Base` is an abstract class, it isn't constructible with anything, so `ConstrWithInt<Base>` is in fact `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a derived abstract test class, which tries to use this constructor:

```
struct Test_Base_Constructors : public Base {
    Test_Base_Constructors(int i) : Base(i) {}
};
```

You get a compiler error, if `Base` can't be constructed with `int`. Testing with *gcc* on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/onPh6e17x) by removing the `int` from `Base` constructor, it gives reasonably nice error message:

```
In constructor 'Test_Base_Constructors::Test_Base_Constructors(int)':
error: no matching function for call to 'Base::Base(int&)'
    8 |     Test_Base_Constructors(int i) : Base(i) {}
...more lines showing candidates
```

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that, because the code which uses Base would also cause a compiler error. I wanted to provide a better error message

Comment: I downvoted this for a few reasons. First, this answer is lacking any real description of how this approach would work. Second, the class in the code doesn't actually derive from `Base`. Third, even if it did derive from `Base` and nothing else, it is *still* not constructible because it does not implement the pure virtual function. Fourth, OP is looking for a more generic solution than needing to manually derive a concrete class and implement its members  for each abstract class they have.

Comment: @AndyG Fixed the missing `Base`. Anyway, this is still abstract class, it does not implement `foo()`.

Comment: @AndyG Also added a bit more stuff, basically error message it gives.

Comment: @yannick818 I don't know how good error message you want, but to me "Test Base Constructor: no matching function to call Base::Base(int)` is pretty good as error messages go. You can name the test class better to make it more clear.